# Migrating from Javadoc to Python Documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

So I've gotten somewhat used to Javadoc style documentation. Looking through various examples of Python code, I'm finding that, at first blush, the documentation *seems* to be missing a lot of information.

The good: vary rarely do you see self-evident bits of documentation. Docstrings are usually a paragraph or less of English markup that integrates instead of standing out on separate lines.

The bad: in conjunction with Python's duck-typing, I find that many functions are unclear about the parameters they expect. There's no type hinting (duck-hinting?) and often times it would be nice to have some idea that the parameter should be list-like, string-like, stream-like.

Of course, Javadoc was designed for a lower-level language, without great introspection abilities of Python, which might account for the less verbose documentation philosophy.

Any advice on Python documentation standards and best-practices?

Comment: It's kind of open ended. I've added that I'm looking for advice.

Comment: Advice on what?  Are you writing software and want to also provide documentation?  Or are you complaining that you can't find things in the Python library documentation?  "Python ... documentation seems to be missing a lot of information" is just a complaint.  What are you having trouble doing?

Comment: I was referring to source code documentation, which appeared less verbose than my experiences with java and php. An observation, not a complaint sir. At the time I was unaware of ReST which turned out to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) format was designed in response to the need for Python documentation that could be embedded in docstrings, so the best thing is to **learn reST and format your docstrings with that format**. You might find, as I did, that you then go on to format just about *any* documentation in reST, but that's a side point :-)

For specifically documenting your Python code, the [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) system is a set of extensions to the reST format, and a build system for rendering documents. Since it was designed to document Python itself, including the standard library, **Sphinx allows for very well-structured documentation of source code**, including of course the specifics of function signatures as you're asking. It allows a comprehensive documentation suite to be built, both auto-extracted and hand-written, all using the same formatting system.

If you *only* want documentation generated from your source code, then **[Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) will extract API documentation from your source code**; it, too, reads reST formatting for the text.

Comment: +1: epydoc is very close to javadoc in the way it works.  Use epytext will feel comfortable because the syntax is similar.  However, switching to RST and using Sphinx produces documentation more flexibly and with a better look.